# Can't get react to render my css grid layout responsively

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, css-grid, grid-layout

I am trying to make a grid for a chess game. 8x8 with 64 squares.
I want the grid to expand and shrink depending on the screen size. I can easily achieve the desired behavior using basic html and a linked css file:

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

.square {
  border: solid black 1px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

However when I try to produce the same result using react rendering a component, I get totally different behavior. The squares do not grow or shrink, they simply spread apart leaving space between the columns.

```html
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/main.jsx"></script>
</body>
```

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Board />
  </React.StrictMode>
```

```
import "./board.css"
export default function Board() {

    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
            <div className="square"></div>
        </div>
    )}
```

I was expecting the grid to expand while maintaining the 1 / 1 aspect ratio and no gaps between columns. Instead, the grid expands by stretching horizontally and introduces gaps between columns without changing the shape or size of the squares.

Comment: I tried to implement your code and it seems everything works fine. I can't see any gaps between the columns. Can you share an image of the issue or any other details to help further

Comment: Thanks! I actually found out the problem had to do with old css files still importing (even though I was no longer explicitly importing them). I simply deleted them and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved my problem. Somehow other css files were being imported into my react project. Even though I was not explicitly importing them any longer. I discovered this using chrome developer tools and found that there was some legacy styling attached to my square elements. After deleting my deprecated css files, the grid-layout is rendering exactly as desired!